# using python default development http server, error, The current URL, , didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am using python default development http server, and it works fine.
Error ,The current URL, , didn't match any of these, after "http://127.0.0.1:8000
MY software version:django 1.4 python 2.6.6

my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
#from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'djproject.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^djproject/', include('djproject.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    #    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
)
```

Errors:

```
Page not found (404)
    Request Method:     GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in djproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^admin/

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only urls installed in your project at the moment are those that are prefixed by `admin/`.

The one you are trying to fetch does not start with this prefix.

Try: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`

It looks like you are just starting out with django: have you worked through the tutorial yet?

Comment: thx it works. yes, I am a newer in it. I am reading the tutorial part02,now.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the commented out "Examples" section among the `urlpatterns` you will se this line:

```
# url(r'^$', 'djproject.views.home', name='home'),
```

That is the pattern and view for the default. Uncomment this, and set the view and parameters you need. And read the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)!